# NSManagedObjectContext's registeredObjects won't return anything unless a fetch is executed beforehand

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Cheers,

I'm experiencing a problem with core data, I guess I'm just looking in the wrong direction again.

My managedObjectContext will return an empty NSSet if I call `registeredObjects` on it. If I execute a fetch beforehand however, it will return the same objects that as the fetch did just a moment ago.

There's no multithreading going on.

Here's what I do:

```
[self setupContext]; // This will set up managedObjectContext, which is a property of this class

// Fetching...    

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *foo = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Foo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:foo];

NSError *fetchError = nil;
NSArray *fetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&ftchError];

NSLog(@"Fetch returned %i objects.", [fetchResults count]);

[request release];

// Done fetching...

NSArray *allObjects = [[managedObjectContext registeredObjects] allObjects];

NSLog(@"Context contains %i objects...", [allObjects count]);
```

The store contains 30 objects. If I run the code above, both NSLogs will report five objects. If I remove the fetch part between the two comments, it will report zero objects for the whole context.

Note that I am at no point commiting or otherwise changing the contexts contents.

Do I need to force the context into refreshing itself first? I've never done this before though and I don't recall `registeredObjects` failing on me like this on other occasions in the first place.

Any suggestions appreciated!
Toastor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be confused about what `registeredObjects` means. This is the set of objects that are currently in the `NSManagedObjectContext`. This is not the set of objects in the store, just the ones in the context. If you haven't fetched or otherwise registered the objects in the context, then they won't be in `registeredObjects`.

Comment: I guess you're right. I've hardly ever used that method and in the past I propably just didn't notice because it had been preceeded by some fetches, which "obscured" the "problem". Can you suggest an alternative for fetching all objects from the store? My model features about 60 entities (don't ask), it appears like a tedious task to me to fetch them all one by one. Thanks alot!

Comment: You can use `-[NSManagedObjectModel entities]` to fetch all the entities, then you can use NSFetchRequest to fetch all the objects of each entity. But what's the real goal? This sounds like you're fighting Core Data.

Comment: True in a way... I need to deal with a very complex exchange format and for ease of use, I just recreated its structure in the core data model. It turns out however that there are a lot of drawbacks to this approach, but I'm kind of stuck with it. What I'm trying to do is to delete all objects, for a number of reasons I wanted to avoid tearing down the stack and deleting the store file. I also need to fetch all objects when serializing the data for the export into the old xchange format. Since it doesn't require the instances to be ordered, fetching all at a time would be the easiest way.